# What's wrong with this MYSQL DELETE statement?

Tags: mysql

I want to delete records from a table greater than a certain message_id.
MY delete statement doesn't seem to working.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f8ee/1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Correct your fiddle `DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.` is the error

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE c
FROM `chat_history3` c
inner join 
(
   select message_id from `chat_history3` 
   where clan_id=4 
   ORDER BY message_id DESC 
   limit 30, 30000
) x
on c.`message_id` < x.`message_id`
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/512a9e/1)